Create multiple circles on the same scene using JavaFX and setOnMouseMoved method
I started coding with JavaFX a couple of days ago and this is one exercise who's been bothering me for the past five hours or so.
I want to add circles to the scene by first clicking where I want the center to be and then moving the cursor to get the radius; also I'm forcing myself not to use Canvas for the time being.
The code below was slightly modified from the one available here:
Draw circle with mouse click points (JavaFX)
in order to leave every drawn circle on the screen.
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestJavaFX extends Application {

    private double cX, cY;
    public boolean firstClick = true;

    @Override

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 960, 540);

        scene.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {

            if (firstClick) {
                cX = evt.getX();
                cY = evt.getY();
                firstClick = false;
            } else {
                double r = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(cX - evt.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(cY - evt.getY(), 2));
                Circle circle = new Circle(cX, cY, r, Color.BLUE);
                root.getChildren().add(circle);
                firstClick = true;
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setTitle("TestJavaFX");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

I've come up with the code above to add circles to the scene by clicking twice but I was not able to replicate the same result using setOnMouseMoved. Putting Circle circle = new Circle() inside a setOnMouseMoved event creates a new circle at every movement of the cursor effectively making impossible to interact with the screen.
---------- Update based on @James_D's suggestion ----------
Despite being a wonderful suggestion and the sequence feeling way more natural, a new circle is being added to root.getChildren() even if a single click is performed without actually dragging the mouse.
In other words root is being populated also by circles having radius equal to zero, created from a user's erroneous click.
You can see what I mean in the image below where I simply added a System.out.println(root.getChildren().size()) to the first event.


Keep a reference to the current circle. On the first click, create a new circle with radius zero, add it to the screen, and set the current circle to it. On the second click, just set first click back to true and do nothing else. In the mouse moved handler, if it's not the first click, change the radius of the current circle.

Note that, once you have it working, you can remove the firstClick flag. Set the current circle to null on the second click, and then just use currentCircle != null to check if the user is currently drawing a circle, or currentCircle == null to see if they need to start a new one.

Also consider using setOnMousePressed(...) to start a new circle, setOnMouseDragged(...) to change its radius, and setOnMouseReleased(...) to "complete the circle". That will give a different (but more natural imo) feel for the user (and the code will be arguably simpler).

Updated my answer in response to the edit. Note of course the same thing happens in the other solutions too; zero-radius circles are added if the user clicks twice without moving the mouse (or clicks, moves the mouse, and clicks again in the same original position).

@James_D Sure, but that would mean two erroneous clicks in a row...it's obviously fusiness and just a way to think thoroughly about the code.

"that would mean two erroneous clicks in a row". Not really. If the user erroneously clicked once, they would need a way to ensure the circle was removed (or not added).  In the click-move-click gesture, they would need to click in exactly the same place. In the click-drag-release gesture they would just need to release without dragging. Ultimately, you might want some kind of "remove" functionality (e.g. undo last add, or right-click a circle to remove it; neither are hard to implement).

Other answers have provided implementations of the functionality as described. For completeness, here is an implementation of the alternative I suggested using press-drag-release as the mouse gesture:
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestJavaFX extends Application {


    private Circle currentCircle;

    @Override

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 960, 540);

        scene.setOnMousePressed(evt -> {
                currentCircle = new Circle(evt.getX(), evt.getY(), 0, Color.BLUE);
                root.getChildren().add(currentCircle);
        });

        scene.setOnMouseDragged(evt -> {
            double cx = currentCircle.getCenterX();
            double cy = currentCircle.getCenterY();
            double edgeX = evt.getX();
            double edgeY = evt.getY();
            double deltaX = cx - edgeX;
            double deltaY = cy - edgeY;
            double r = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
            currentCircle.setRadius(r);
        });

        scene.setOnMouseReleased( _ -> {
            if (currentCircle.getRadius() < 1) {
                root.getChildren().remove(currentCircle);
            }
            currentCircle = null;
        });

        primaryStage.setTitle("TestJavaFX");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

Note that in this case the code is simpler, in that there is no testing needed to see what state the drawing process is in. That state is inherent in the semantics of the different types of mouse event (press to start a new circle, drag to change the radius, release to stop drawing). There's also less state to track: the only instance variable is the "current circle".
In the onMouseReleased handler here I removed the current circle if the radius is less than one pixel. This allows the user to "change their mind" and not add the circle after clicking, by releasing the mouse without dragging it. (Thanks to @SedJ601 for the suugestion.) Ultimately, it might be good to implement some "undo" (e.g. a key pressed handler on the scene handling shortcut+z to remove the last circle) or "remove" (e.g. right-click on the circle to remove it) functionality. Neither of these are difficult to implement, but are, as is commonly said in text books, left as exercises for the reader.

My answer is very similar to yours, with one exception. In my setOnMouseReleased, I removed the circle from the scene if its radius was zero.

I absolutely agree the sequence setOnMousePressed -> setOnMouseDragged -> setOnMouseReleased feels more natural to the user.

To solve this and get behavior you want (clicking to set the center of the circle and then dragging the mouse to set the radius), you can make a few adjustments to your code. The main issue you're facing with setOnMouseMoved is that you're creating  new Circle at every mouse movement, which causes screen to get overloaded with circle.
What you need to do is create the circle when the mouse is click, but then update it radias dynamicully as the mouse moves. You only need to create a single circle and adjust it radius on mouse movement, instead of creating a new circle each time.
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestJavaFX extends Application {

    private double cX, cY;
    private Circle circle; // Keep a reference to the circle
    public boolean firstClick = true;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 960, 540);

        scene.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
            if (firstClick) {
                cX = evt.getX();
                cY = evt.getY();
                // Create the circle only on the first click
                circle = new Circle(cX, cY, 0, Color.BLUE);
                root.getChildren().add(circle);
                firstClick = false;
            } else {
                // Reset the firstClick flag if the second click is used to confirm the circle
                firstClick = true;
            }
        });

        // Update the circle radius dynamically as the mouse moves
        scene.setOnMouseMoved(evt -> {
            if (!firstClick && circle != null) {
                double r = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(cX - evt.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(cY - evt.getY(), 2));
                circle.setRadius(r);
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setTitle("TestJavaFX");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}


If I understand correctly, you want the circle to visibly resize while you move the mouse around until you click the mouse again. You'll need to keep a reference to the Circle currently being added for that. Then in the mouse-moved handler, you would update the circle's radius if there's a circle being added. The implementation might look something like:
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  private Pane circlesPane;
  private Circle currentCircle;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    circlesPane = new Pane();
    circlesPane.setOnMouseClicked(this::handleMouseClicked);
    circlesPane.setOnMouseMoved(this::handleMouseMoved);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(circlesPane, 600, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private void handleMouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    e.consume();
    if (currentCircle == null) {
      var fill = new Color(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1.0);
      currentCircle = new Circle(e.getX(), e.getY(), 0, fill);
      circlesPane.getChildren().add(currentCircle);
    } else {
      currentCircle = null;
    }
  }

  private void handleMouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    if (currentCircle != null) {
      e.consume();
      double x1 = currentCircle.getCenterX();
      double y1 = currentCircle.getCenterY();
      double x2 = e.getX();
      double y2 = e.getY();
      double radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
      currentCircle.setRadius(radius);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(Main.class);
  }
}

Note how whether currentCircle is null or not is used to determine if a circle is being added, which replaces your firstClick boolean field. This improvement was also suggested by James_D. And see another one of their suggestions:

Also consider using setOnMousePressed(...) to start a new circle, setOnMouseDragged(...) to change its radius, and setOnMouseReleased(...) to "complete the circle". That will give a different (but more natural imo) feel for the user (and the code will be arguably simpler)

(I agree the press-drag-release gesture would feel more natural.) See James_D's answer.
